# WSDL Calling Web Service; Server was unable to process request ---&gt; System.Security.AuthenticationException

Tags: c#-4.0, soap, wsdl

I have a program that send a request through to a web service via a WSDL structure and then recieves a response. Currently the response I am recieving is:

```
    <soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt;   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Failed to authenticate Rewards service - (5.0.0):Authentication with the SecurityService has failed for username 'exam269'
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.RewardsServiceState.GetPrincipal(Boolean&amp; fromLocalCache, Boolean&amp; fromP3Cache) in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\RewardsServiceState.cs:line 105
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.ServiceMethodCall`2.GenerateController() in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\ServiceMethodCall.cs:line 254
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.ServiceMethodCall`2.get_Controller() in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\ServiceMethodCall.cs:line 27
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.ServiceMethodCall`2.LogResponse() in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\ServiceMethodCall.cs:line 245
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.ServiceMethodCall`2.Execute() in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\ServiceMethodCall.cs:line 149
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.ServiceMethodCall`2.ServiceCallMethodFluentHandler.Execute() in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\ServiceMethodCall.cs:line 88
at P3Rewards.ServiceHost.RewardsService.NewMemberRegistration(String source, NewMember registerMember) in c:\Development\P3Rewards\Source\P3Rewards.ServiceHost\RewardsService.asmx.cs:line 163
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring>
  <detail />
</soap:Fault>
```

Any ideas as to what has gone wroing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably provided wrong credentials.You have the following in the trace:

```
Authentication with the SecurityService has failed for username 'exam269'
```

From MSDN description of the exception, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.authenticationexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The **NegotiateStream** and **SslStream** classes throw this exception when
>   the client or server cannot be authenticated. When this exception is
>   thrown, you can ***retry the authentication with different credentials***.
>   If you cannot retry the authentication, a **FatalAuthenticationException**
>   is thrown instead of the **AuthenticationException**.